# How to gather information from a URL and decode it in another application

Tags: javascript, json, decoder

I'm looking to create a web based tool that will allow me to pull information from a website via URL and decode this content in a more usable fashion.

Here is the situation: The company I work for has log files any time there is an error in the code. The error's are then searchable in a back end application but contain raw data and is fairly time consuming to find the useful information. Those logs are then accessible with a static link.

I'm pretty sure I can figure out the decoding process, however I am struggling with how to get the content I need to decode.

The content I am looking to decode is not on the same domain but are within my companies network.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Maybe with a server side language (PHP?)? Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Putvande I haven't tried anything yet. I was looking into how to go about it initially and so far I am seeing that I am fairly limited but in talking with a few people I have heard there is a Function in 'json' that might help be accomplish this by saving the page to a file. From there I am confident I can then reference the file and pull the information I need.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not on your domaine you can't request the link using javascript, so you need to do it in the backend with `curl` or other HTTP clients.